# Join two list using LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, console-application

I am trying to join two lists and implement LINQ query on them to display White and Black cars from these two lists, so far code does the job, but that not the result that I exactly wanted, here is my code:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>
    {
        new Cars { Make = "Honda", Model = 2000, Color = "Black" },
        new Cars { Make = "Suzuki", Model = 1999, Color = "White" },
        new Cars { Make = "Toyota", Model = 2020, Color = "Green" },
        new Cars { Make = "Kia", Model = 2020, Color = "Blue" }
    };
     List<MakeBy> makeby = new List<MakeBy>
        {
            new MakeBy { Make = "Tesla", Model = 1998, Color = "Black" },
            new MakeBy { Make = "Audi", Model = 2015, Color = "White" },
            new MakeBy { Make = "Mercedes", Model = 2021, Color = "Green" },
            new MakeBy { Make = "Ford", Model = 1991, Color = "Blue" }
        };
    var CombineCars = cars.Join(makeby,
                        c => c.Color,
                        m => m.Colour,
                        (c, m) => new
                        {
                            carMake = c.Make,
                            carModel = c.Model,
                            carColor = c.Color,
                            makeByColor = m.Colour,
                            makeByCountry = m.Country
                        });
    foreach (var car in CombineCars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Car model: {car.carModel}, car make: {car.carMake}, Car Color: {car.carColor}, Make By: {car.makeByCountry}, Make Color is: {car.makeByColor}"); 
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This piece of code displaying this result:

```
Car model: 2000, car make: Honda, Car Color: Black, Make By: Japan, Make Color is: Black
Car model: 1999, car make: Suzuki, Car Color: White, Make By: China, Make Color is: White
Car model: 1999, car make: Suzuki, Car Color: White, Make By: Japan, Make Color is: White
Car model: 1999, car make: Suzuki, Car Color: White, Make By: Korea, Make Color is: White
```

There is only one WHITE CAR in the first list, why my code displaying 2 more white cars after joining these two lists? Please tell me if there is an improved way for displaying these lists after joining.

Comment: Your logic seemed strange to me. `Car` is ok but what is `MakeBy`? It is should be an operation, it is not a class. I mean you should use it as a method because it is confusing your logic or you should use the country as an association relationship in car. You got other white cars because their countries are different.

Comment: @gurkan you are right, but this is my assignment:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you just want to filter the joined list, if this is the case, then this might work:

```
var combinedCars = from c in cars
               where c.Color == "White" || c.Color == "Black"
               join m in makeby on c.Color equals m.Color
               select new
               {
                   carMake = c.Make,
                   carModel = c.Model,
                   carColor = c.Color,
                   makeByColor = m.Color,
                   makeByModel = m.Model,
                   makeByMake = m.Make
               };
```

**Courtesy: Richard Deeming**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve list of items from `cars` collection then you can use `Select` method with `Where` to filter by `Color` property:

```
var filtered = cars
   .Where(w => w.Color == "Black" || w.Color == "White")
   .Select(s => new
   {
       s.Make,
       s.Model,
       s.Color,
       MakeByColor = makeby.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Colour == s.Color)?.Colour,
       MakeByCountry = makeby.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Colour == s.Color)?.Country
   });
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use `Union` method to union non related items:

```
var uniqueMakeby = makeby.Select(s => s.Colour).Distinct();            
var selectedCars = cars
    .Where(w => uniqueMakeby.Contains(w.Color))
    .Select(s => new
    {
        s.Make,
        s.Model,
        s.Color,
        Country = string.Empty
    });
var unioned = selectedCars.Union(
    from x in makeby select new 
    { 
        Make = string.Empty, 
        Model = 0, 
        Color = x.Colour, 
        x.Country
     }
);
```

Comment: somehow this query omits these two new MakeBy { Colour = "White", Country = "Japan" },
            new MakeBy { Colour = "White", Country = "Korea" } from the result

Comment: I want the result that will show the first two cars from the 'cars' list and then all four cars from the second list 'makeby' because of their color, i update it in my question

Comment: thank you so much, sorry for the late response, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behaviour. Join will find all records in second list which has the same value and filter out records which do not have value on the right side.

According to the data, you cannot use `Join` here, but `Zip`

```cs
var CombineCars = cars.Zip(makeby,
    (c, m) => new
    {
        carMake = c.Make,
        carModel = c.Model,
        carColor = c.Color,
        makeByColor = m.Colour,
        makeByCountry = m.Country
    });
```

Comment: Please re-read my question, I edit my question, I want to display the only WHITE and BLACK cars from these two lists.

Comment: I'm not good in a telepathy. Post desired result from two lists and how do you plan to make join in this case.